# How to access to parameters in a Jenkins Template?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have this template:

```
def call(body) {

    def pipelineParams= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    pipeline {

        agent any

        ....

        stages {

            stage('My stages') {
                steps {

                    script {

                        pipelineParams.stagesParams.each { k, v ->
                            if (k.toLowerCase().startsWith("If ") && (params[ k.split(' ')[1] ] as boolean)) {                                
                                stage("$k") {
                                   $v
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        post { ... }
    }
}
```

and a relative pipeline that uses this template:

```
@Library('pipeline-library') _

pipelineMyTemplate {

    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'foo', defaultValue: true, description: 'some option')
        booleanParam(name: 'bar', defaultValue: true, description: 'some option')
    }

    stagesParams = [
        'If foo run': echo "foo is selected",
        'If bar run': echo "bar is selected"
    ]
}
```

In the pipeline where I wrote `if (some option selected in the parameters)` how can I reference to the parameters if not there yet? Also I noticed that the options are not display in the UI as checkboxes when created in that way.

Comment: Uh.. I think that brought you in the wrong direction. I *think* that you can't use `when` in scripted context. Your `if` was better. Still.. please try to access parameters with `params.parameterName`. That still sounds to me like what you're looking for. This returns `null` IIRC at the very first run, when it's not yet defined in the pipeline options.

Comment: I removed the `when` and moved the condition on the main `if`. However I do not understand how to `params.parameterName` if the parameter name needs to be extracted dynamically from the text.

Comment: Ah, it so you don't know, if you want `params.foo` or `params.bar`? Could be that it works with `params['foo']` and `params[var]` as well.. or some other groovy magic like `params.get(var)`..?

Comment: that is what I already do with `params[ k.split(' ')[1] ]`

Comment: okay, then I still don't get the problem and would leave it up to others to solve it with you

Comment: `k.toLowerCase().startsWith("If ")` is going to be a problem since 'If' is not lower case

Comment: That’s why there is the toLowerCase

Answer (score 0):

1. I think pipeline scripts do not have boolean parameter. So as a workaround you need to try `parameterAsBoolean = (BAR == "true")
2. To my knowledge you can't have stage within a step, so adjust it accordingly and see if it works for you.